# convert from teradata to oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

Please help me in converting following query written in teradata to oracle sql.

```
SELECT cast((substr( CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AS varchar(19)), 1,4) as decimal(18,0)) as termid from source1
```

Comment: SO is not a free code conversion service. Make an elfor to do the conversion yourself. When you've done so and run into issues, you can explain that problem, add the relevant portions of both the old code and your code, and ask a specific question related to that code and we can try to help. You'll find your expreiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works and what our expectations are before  you begin posting.

Comment: Seems to be a simple `extract(year from current_timestamp)` which works in both Teradata and Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have to use to_char with timestamp explicitly since timestamp format can contain words

```
  SELECT cast(substr( to_char(current_timestamp(0),'DDMM'), 1,4) 
  as decimal(18,0)) as termid from dual
```

Comment: SELECT cast(substr( to_char(current_timestamp(0),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 1,4) 
  as number(18,0)) as termid from dual. Thanks @psaraj12

Comment: @Ali it makes no sense to use a long format string, and afterwards cut out the year using substr. Just use a format string of  `'YYYY'`

Answer (score 1):

Your current calculation extracts the year as numeric value. In both Teradata and Oracle this can be achieved easily using

```
extract(year from current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current year, this will do it in Oracle:

```
select to_char(Current_Timestamp(0),'YYYY') termid from dual;
```